# How can I remove index.php from http://example.com/index.php/member/reset_password?&id=GHbFGYJM ? ExpressionEngine3

Tags: members, forgot-password, rewrite

The link is sent to me in an email when I reset my password via front end login form and works as it should when I remove the index.php from the url. I have already created a rule in .htaccess to remove index.php from urls.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

     # Admin Access
    RewriteRule ^(admin)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your admin panel, Go to General configurations settings and set **Name of your site's index page** to **blank** or via FTP edit your config.php file inside config folder and add `$config['site_index'] = ""`